# How to use loops with mouseButton in Processing

Tags: loops, processing

I'm new to programming and took a intro class to processing and for one of my school projects I decided to make a "game" where the user uses the left and right buttons to "go to that direction". I want to make it as if the user clicks both the left and mouse button more than 10 times, the program will break from the loop and exit the game.

I tried to use the same format as a for loop but replaced the int value with the button control but i keep on getting a missing operator message. This is my code:

```java
    void draw() {
      photo = loadImage("https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/mackenzie-shirk-highresscreenshot00005-1920x1080-3eed278c8730ae28130aca96322a23d1.jpg");
      image(photo, 100, 100);
      print(f);
      if (mousePressed && (mouseButton == LEFT)) {
        //if left button is clicked, you text tells you that you go left println(a);
      } else if (mousePressed && (mouseButton == RIGHT)) {
        //if right button is clicked, text tells you that you go right println(b);
      }
      for (mouseButton == LEFT \> 10) {
        //if string a is print more than 10 times, break break;
      }
      for (mouseButton == RIGHT \> 10) {
        //if string b is print more than 10 times, break break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code that you posted and several areas that you need to work on.

1. When posting to Stack Overflow please format your source code by either placing it within code blocks ({}) or between two sets of grave accents,
   ```
   code here
   ```
2. The image should be loaded in setup().  Most Processing apps have both setup() and draw() functions.
3. The image does load, but won't be displayed unless you use a larger window size.
4. To keep track of the number of right and left clicks I would suggest using two global integer variables: one for rightClick and one for leftClick.
5. To trap only one click at a time it would be better to use mousePressed() and trap the right and left clicks inside of this.
6. 'break;' only works in 'for' loops and 'switch' and 'while' constructs.  If you want to leave the app when a certain number of clicks is exceeded, exit() would work better.
7. Processing uses println() for console logs instead of print().
8. The title of your post mentions an array, but there are no arrays in your code.

Keep reading and writing code and good luck with your project.

The following source code should run without error and demonstrates the points outlined above:

```
PImage photo;
int leftCounter = 0;
int rightCounter = 0;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  photo = loadImage("https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/item/mackenzie-shirk-highresscreenshot00005-1920x1080-3eed278c8730ae28130aca96322a23d1.jpg");
}

void draw() {
  image(photo, 0, 0, photo.width/2, photo.height/2);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    println("left mouse clicked", leftCounter);
    leftCounter++;
    if (leftCounter > 10) exit();
  }
  if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    println("right mouse clicked", rightCounter);
    rightCounter++;
    if (rightCounter > 10) exit();
  }
}
```